# Extract specific string from Excel cell using a identifier | MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to extract a particular string from a excel cell using excel formula.

Input string:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${SCHEMA_NM}.beneficiary_enriched STORED AS ORC tblproperties("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")   AS  SELECT DISTINCT source, individual_analytics_identifier,    preferred_proxy_id, demogr_first_name,  demogr_last_name,   birth_date, gender, zip_code,   state,  coverage_effective_date,    coverage_expiration_date    FROM    ${SCHEMA_NM}.beneficiary_decrypted;
```

Output string:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| ${SCHEMA_NM}.beneficiary_enriched | ${SCHEMA_NM}.beneficiary_decrypted |

Want to extract table name from create statement. col1 has 'new table name' and col2 has 'from table name' starting from '$'

Formula i tried:(not working in all cases)

For getting new table name:

````
=MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1)+1,(LEN(A1)-(SEARCH("$",A1)+1))-(LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,((LEN(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("$",A1)-1))+1)))))```

Help me get the correct output.
````

Comment: So write another to deal with the odd cases, choose with if() or iferror().

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming the only dollar signs are those to indicate your desired substrings.

---

**Excel ms365 BETA-Channel:**

[image]

Formula in `B4`:

```
="$"&TOROW(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"$",{" ",";"}),,-1),3)
```

**Note:** To assert we only split on dollar signs of interest we could add a space inside: `TEXTSPLIT(A1," $",{" ",";"})`. That would leave other dollar signs alone.

---

**Excel ms365:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'$')]"))
```

---

**Excel 2013 (or higher):**

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'$')]"),COLUMN(A1))
```

And drag right.

**Note:** For both the `FILTERXML()` options we allready assert that the 1st character is a dollar sign. If you want to be more explicit you can add the curly brackets inside the xpath for example: `"//s[starts-with(.,'${')]"`

Comment: Thanks @JvDV for responding. But none of the formulas are working. Giving #value! and #name?! as outputs.

Comment: As per input given in your query, the formulas provided above should work, there is no issue with the formulas unless you have something else. Could you update your query to show us where it is not working for you. All the formulas provided above are working formulas,